# How to combine a sequence of dataframes

Tags: r, join, dataframe, merge, sequence

I have a sequence of a 100 data frames. They all have the same prefix. But the suffixes go from 1 to 100.  Instead of writing out the names of all same hundred data frames, is there a shorter way?

```
new.d<-rbind(d1, d2, d3, d4, d5, d6...d100)
```

Is there a shorter way than having to write out the names of a 100 data frames? They all have the same names, but they are just numbered sequentially with different suffixes.

Comment: try `new.d <- eval(parse(text=paste0("rbind(",toString(paste0("d",1:100)),")")))`

Comment: Advice for the future: Don't get yourself in that situation in the first place.  I'm guessing you created the dataframes like this. It might have been better to just store them into a list directly.

Comment: Thanks, that code worked. How would I get them into a list as you suggest?

Comment: Mary, I believe the solution [posted here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499013/how-do-i-make-a-list-of-data-frames/24376207#24376207) should address all of your questions.